# Tkinter Change Label to default font

Tags: tkinter, fonts, default

I am trying to change a Tkinter Label's font to default after a button has been pressed. The Label is initially set as bold, underlined, with font size 10, using the following code

```
Label32.config(font=('Helvetica', 10, 'bold','underline'))
```

When the button is pressed the Label should NOT be bold anymore, NOT be underlined anymore, and with font size 8. I am currently using the following code, but it does not work:

```
Label32.config(font=('TkDefaultFont', 8, 'not bold','not underline'))
```

I have tried searching but most results pertain to changing Tkinter's default font.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to set the font to `"TkDefaultFont"`

```
Label32.config(font=('TkDefaultFont'))
```